# setInterval halted when I move between browser tabs in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const {useState, useEffect, useRef} = React;
function Countdown({ interval = 1000, value = 0 }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useInterval(
    () => {
      setCount(prev => prev - 1);
      if (count - 1 === 0) {
      }
    },
    count > 0 ? interval : null
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    //ComponentDidMount
    const ms = 1000 / interval;
    setCount(value * ms);
    return () => {
      //ComponentWillUnmount
    };
  }, [value, interval]);
  return <div>{count}</div>;
}

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <p>This count works well even if I move to another tab</p>
      <Countdown value={300} />
      <p>This count doesnt work when I move to another tab</p>
      <Countdown interval={100} value={300} />
      <p>This count also doesnt work when I move to another tab</p>
      <Countdown interval={10} value={300} />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Why it happens and how can I solve this problem?

**Edited**

I've found why it happened, but I don't know how to solve...

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript setInterval doesn't work correctly when tab is not active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872185/javascript-setinterval-doesnt-work-correctly-when-tab-is-not-active)

Comment: @Balastrong Thank you for the answer, but in my case `setInterval()` halted only `100ms` and `10ms`

Comment: i do not know react, if you already have rxjs you can use `interval(milliseconds).takeUntil(this.unsubscribeAll).subscribe(()=>dosomething())`
where unsubscribeAll is another observable that fire event when the "component" or the page is destroyed.
I often use this in Angular

Comment: This problem caused by browser policy. it's not about the inaccuracy of countdown. ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

Comment: Both `100ms` and esp `10ms` (which is below frame animation interval 16ms) is "too precise" for using timers. Use `Date.now` or `performance.now` to track how much time is tracked instead of "ticks"

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I don't track time. I will just count down what I set. 
Follow the policy, Timeouts in inactive tabs throttled to ≥ `1000ms`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko you can see the policy here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Timeouts%20in%20inactive%20tabs%20throttled%20to%20%E2%89%A5%201000ms

Comment: "I don't track time." well you do :) in an indirect manner by counting ticks. Just keep start date in a ref and then use `setCount(Math.floor((start.current - performance.now())/interval))`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko and how can you display the animation that count is updated every `100ms`? not `1000ms`. even if I move the browser tab.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I don't think it is a duplicated question.